# QtCurve vs Oxygen GTK theme

Tags: kde, gtk, themes

Is there any difference between [QtCurve](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=40492) and [Oxygen GTK+ theme](http://art4linux.org/node/405) for running GTK applications in KDE? Is Oxygen GTK  better for me to use since I'm using the Oxygen theme anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The QTCurve theme does not try and mimic the default look and feel of KDE in any way. It is a theme that gives your GTK-based application a QT-styled appearance, but it will make your GTK-based application stand out and look different to your KDE applications.

The Oxygen theme will make applications both look and feel similar whether they are QT-/KDE- or GTK-based, and the oxygen developer go through much effort of making sure the oxygen gtk theme makes GTK-based applications not just "look" like QT/KDE applications, but also have the same "feel".

For more information on the effort put into the oxygen gtk theme, you can have a look here:
http://hugo-kde.blogspot.com/2011/06/oxygen-gtk-11-is-out.html
and here:
http://hugo-kde.blogspot.com/2011/04/taste-of-things-to-come.html

Comment: Another difference is that QtCurve does not work on GTK3 applications, while Oxygen-gtk does.